# Access JavaScript Object through point notation

Tags: javascript

I have an JavaScript object with that structure

```
myJsObject= {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [84.1, 99.1]
        },
        "properties": {
            "value": "20",
            "s": "abc"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [18.15, 9.73]
        },
        "properties": {
            "value": "0",
            "s": "def"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [1.15, 4.78]
        },
        "properties": {
            "value": "10",
            "s": "fdg"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [17.15, 5.13]
        },
        "properties": {
            "value": "5",
            "s": "dfs"
        }
    }]
}
```

I try to access it that way:

```
myJsObject.features.forEach(function(d) {
    d.LatLng = new L.LatLng(d.geometry.coordinates[1],
        d.geometry.coordinates[0]);
});
```

That returns me `undefined`.
I can access like so

```
myJsObject.features;
```

and like this

```
myJsObject.features[0];
```

But not like this

```
myJsObject.features.geometry;
```

Why is that? I need the latter for fr `forEach loop`...

Comment: Has nothing to do with JSON, you just have a JavaScript object.

Comment: There's no JSON in your question. — http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @Quentin Your right. I edited :)

Comment: *"That returns me `undefined`."* `forEach` doesn't return anything, so that's expected? The code looks fine to me. `d.geometry.coordinates[1]` is certainly correct. *"I need the latter for fr `forEach` loop"* I don't see why you would.

Comment: Do you know how arrays work? Do you know how to reference an index in an array? Do you know how to iterate over arrays?

Comment: @FelixKling **That returns me undefined."** means that the `forEach` says there is nothing int `d.geometry.coordinates[1]`

Comment: @Stophface: Then your actual data or code must be different because *what you posted works for me*: https://jsfiddle.net/rydwk7t3/ .

Comment: @Stophface — http://jsbin.com/qagopox/1/edit?js,console — Those values are not undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is that?

The value of `myJson.features` is an array.

It is not an object with a property called `geometry`.

The array *contains* objects with properties called `geometry`.

Comment: okay. So within the `forEach` I change to `d[0].geometry....` and that still returns me all my data?

Comment: @Stophface — No. The first argument (`d`) of the callback to the `forEach` is the item in the array that is currently being looped over. It is already `[0]` (or `[1]` or whatever point in the loop it has got to). The code for accessing the values from the object inside the `forEach` is fine.

Comment: Hm, well thats the thing. It tells me `Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` and points me to the line `myJsObject.features.forEach(function(d) {...` When I print the `myJsObject` to the console, I see that it not empty.

Comment: @Stophface: That means that `myJsObject` doesn't have a property `features` (`myJsObject.features` is `undefined`). It has nothing to do with what's inside the callback. Are you sure `myJsObject` is an object and not a **string** containing JSON? What does `typeof myJsObject` give you?

Comment: @Stophface — http://jsbin.com/qagopox/1/edit?js,console — I can't reproduce that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because features is an array of objects you'll need to use this format `myJson.features[0].geometry`

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of features, each with a geometry, which then has a coordinates array. So you could access like this:

```
myJson.features.forEach(function(feature) {
  console.log("lat: " + feature.geometry.coordinates[0]);
  console.log("long: " + feature.geometry.coordinates[1]);
});
```